# All data (key-value pairs) was erased from a child when i tried to save data by passing "" for key and value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase.

My declaration, initialisation and impletementation was as below:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference schoolNamesDatabaseReference;
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
schoolNamesDatabaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("schoolNames");
AutoCompleteTextView schoolNameET = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
String schoolName = schoolNameET.getText().toString;
//schoolNameEt can be empty.

if (!MainMenuActivity.schoolsList.contains(schoolName)){ // schoolName is a string and can be ""
        String schoolNameString = schoolName;
        //Removing '.' , '#' , etc. from schoolName
        schoolName = schoolName.replace(".","");
        schoolName = schoolName.replace("#","");
        schoolName = schoolName.replace("$","");
        schoolName = schoolName.replace("[","");
        schoolName = schoolName.replace("]","");
        //Using schoolName as a key (or say child) and schoolNameString as its value.
        schoolNamesDatabaseReference.child(schoolName).setValue(schoolNameString);
    }
```

My initial database structure was as below:

```
"root-node" : {
    "schoolNames" : {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2", // and more...
                    }
              }
```

When I tried to save data to my Firebase Realtime Database, when `AutoCopleteTextView` is empty(means setting `schoolNames` as `""` and calling`schoolNamesDatabaseReference.child(schoolName).setValue(schoolNameString);`) my database structure becomes as follow:

```
"root-node" : {
    "schoolNames" : ""

              }
```

Means all the previous data was erased from the `"schoolNames"`.

**Why is it happening?**

> Note: There is no error when there is some string in `schoolName` variable.

Comment: where do you change `schoolNameString` before set to database `schoolNamesDatabaseReference.child(schoolName).setValue(schoolNameString);`?

Comment: sorry @MehranZamani I could not understand your question!. Are you asking about why i am using `schoolNameString` ?

Comment: you didn't change value of it

Comment: @MehranZamani I am not changing the value of `schoolNameString`. I am am changing the value of `schoolName`.

Comment: why? what do you want to do?

Comment: sorry @MehranZamani , there is little modification in the question. BTW I  want to use `schoolName` as `key` as well as `value`. Since i can not use `schoolName` as-it-is for `key` since some special characters are not allowed in `key`. So I am storing value of `schoolName` in `schoolNameString` and modifying ` schoolName`. Then passing `schoolName` as key and `schoolNameString` as its value. I hope you understand.

Comment: so at the end when you finished replacing special characters, what's `schoolName` value?
you can't have `null` name as a child of "root-node".

Comment: @MehranZamani Let `schoolName = "some sch. name#"` then at the end when finished replacing special character, value of `schoolName` will be `some sch name`.  Child of `"root-node"` is not `null`, it is `"schoolName"`, and i am adding key-value pair in this child.

Comment: update your question by determine what do you want your database to look like and i send answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `setValue()` method instead of [updateChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) method. Firebase database is structured as a pair of key and value, so in case of `Map`, it replaces the old value with the new one. So to solve this, use DatabaseReference's [updateChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) method and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Pls note that I am not updating the "schoolNames", I am adding new pairs to it.

Comment: To add new parirs, you need to use `updateChildren()` method, as mentioned above, otherwise you will override your data.

Comment: But override problem occurs only when I am passing an empty text for key. I was able to add pairs through my app  using the same code, but passing some valid string.

Comment: Yes, this is what is happening. Try to update the records using an if statement, `if(!text.equals(""))`...

Answer (score 0):

to do this:

```
"root-node" : {
    "schoolNames" : {
        "key":"value1",
        "key":"value2", // and more...
        "key":"NEW_VALUE",
                    }
              }
```

you should write this code:

```
schoolNamesDatabaseReference.child("key").setValue("NEW_VALUE");
```

Comment: yes! the second one. But when i am setting "NEW_KEY" as `""`, all the pairs under `"schoolNames"` are replaced with `""`.And it becoms `"schoolName" : ""`. i.e. all the previous pairs are deleted. >Pls note that I am not updating the "schoolNames", I am adding new pairs to it.

Comment: do you have `schoolNames` class?

Comment: then how you add <"key1","value1"> and <"key2,value2"> ?

Comment: `databseReference.child("schoolNames");` `databaseReference.child("key").setValue("value");`